# @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id) Does not work, but <input type="hidden" value = @Model.Id> works. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am really really confused rigthht now, because I thought that `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)` and 
`<input id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value=@Model.Id>` is the same thing, except for some benefits of the first variant. But If I use the first variant and look into generated html value of input is always = 1, and if I use the second variant - everything is OK.

So here is my view model:

```
public class CheckListViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CheckTime { get; set; }
    public List<QuestionViewModel> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

My view code:

```
@using System.Diagnostics
@using WebCheckList.Models
@model  CheckListViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "CheckList", new {ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl}, FormMethod.Post, new {@class = "form-horizontal", role = "form"}))
{
    //this one does not work. It generates the same html code as 
    // a line below it, only difference is that its value is always = 1
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id); 
    //When I change it to this - everything works.
    <input id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value=@Model.Id>

    ...
```

MVC version is 5.2.0.0
Please, tell me, what have I done wrong, and why the @Html helper does not work properly?

UPDATE:

Contoller looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Questions(int  id)
{
    return Create(new CheckList(), id);
}

public ActionResult Create(CheckList checkList, int checkListsTypeID = 2)
{
    _db.CheckLists.Add(checkList);
    _db.SaveChanges();

    var checkListViewModel = new CheckListViewModel {Questions = questions, Id = checkList.ID, CheckTime = checkList.CheckTime};
    return View("Details", checkListViewModel);
}
```

Is my problem happening because I return one method result from another?

Comment: I think  you should provide controller code.Dou you chabge id in controller code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try change id name in action method for example questionId.

```
public ActionResult Questions(int  questionId)
{
    return Create(new CheckList(), id);
}
```

**Upd:**
I have found SO question that exacly will help you.

[SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748940/hiddenforx-x-id-is-being-populated-by-the-urlparameter-instead-of-the-viewm)

Comment: Thats some unexpected behavior there.